# Compare times between vector and matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I need to compare times of a vector `x` and a matrix `y`.
For example the vector `x`:

```
x = [1.472426760000000e+09; 1.472430300000000e+09; 1.472433840000000e+09; 1.472435100000000e+09]
```

and the matrix `y`:

```
y = [1.472426760000000e+09, 1.472430300000000e+09, 1.472435100000000e+09;
     1.472430300000000e+09, 1.472430300000000e+09, 1.472426760000000e+09;
     1.472433840000000e+09, 1.472430300000000e+09, 1.472435100000000e+09]
```

I want to find out which times of vector `x` is also in matrix `y`. And if not, just write `NaN`. The resulting matrix should the have the same dimensions like matrix y.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to check for membership between two arrays. It will return a logical array the size of the first input that is `true` wherever the value is in the second input and `false` otherwise.

```
tf = ismember(y, x);
```

You can then use this result to replace all of the values that aren't in `y` with `NaN`

```
y(~tf) = NaN;
```

In your example data, all of the values in `y` are also in `x` so there will be no `NaN` values.

**Update**

If you want the location of the values of `x` within `y`, then you can use the second output of `ismember` to provide you with this information:

```
[tf, ind] = ismember(y, x);
```

Comment: Hey Suever, that works quite well! However, I would also like to have the index of the vector x in the new matrix - where a value of x equals a value of matrix y.

Comment: @EnzoBruckmamaan Updated. I think you're referring to the second output of `ismember`